# How to fix a single column in horizontal scrolling of mat-table in Angular Material 2

Tags: angular5, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material 2 with Angular 5. I am using mat-table. I want to fix a single column in mat-table. When i scroll the horizontal bar then a column will fix and not scrolling. Is there possible to fixed a column in mat-table.

[Angular Material 2: mat-table link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qldmqdpqbqk?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score 6):

From [material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview):

> It is also possible to fix cell columns to the start or end of the horizontally scrolling viewport. To do this, add the sticky or stickyEnd directive to the ng-container column definition.

Here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rormaeoyerj?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.html)